# Spark yarn executor process use more than 1000% cpu when I pass the parameter --executor-core=1

Tags: apache-spark, cpu-usage

When I run a spark program, I use the parameter `--executor-core=1`, but the node server gets some CPU usage warnings, then I use the command "top" and find one process exceed 1000% CPU! 
according to the parameter `--executor-core=1` then the process should possess 100% CPU or a little bit more, but the result is some process own 1000%+ CPU. I want to know how that happened and how I can resolve it?
[image: CPU usage screenshot]

Comment: Edit your question and explain "some CPU usage warnings". The best would be to paste / include it right in your question. How do you submit your Spark application? List all the parameters (on command line, properties files, env vars). What's the Spark version?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski  I just supervisor the cpu,and the usage of cpu exceeds 80%

Comment: Can you answer the other questions?